# Setting bilingual text

Tags: page-breaking

How might one set a Greek text on even pages with English translation on odd? I suppose one could break the pages manually unless there is an easy better way.

Comment: You could check the `parallel` package and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86366/7883 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267101/7883 and questions tagged `parallel` could help you.

Comment: There is the `reledpar` package for parallel typesetting of critical editions --- oriiginal and translation on opposite pages --- though you probably won't need all the bells and whistles it provides.

Answer (score 2):

I came to this question because I wanted to know how to write a bilingual Text divided in odd and even (or left/right) pages.

I checked the package `parallel` and the links in the comments.

There were some examples but none of them were simple and complete to present a two page bilingual document.

As I will update a whole book into the bilingual-two-pages format, I present below the MWE I made to understand the concept and how `parallel` behaves.

I know this question is old, but it still was without a direct answer to it. This might help in the future.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage[german, brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

CAPE -- MWE package parallel with bilingual

\clearpage

Before.

Pay attention to odd-even to start the text.

The next page is blank because the first \textbf{parallel} is \textbf{left}.

\begin{Parallel}[p]{}{}
    \ParallelLText{ %
        \selectlanguage{german}

        Dieser Text ist auf Deutsch.

        left-text 1

        \lipsum[1-3]
    }
    \ParallelRText{ %
        \selectlanguage{brazil}

        Este texto está em alemão.

        right-text 1

        \lipsum[1-3]
    }
    \ParallelPar
    \ParallelLText{ %
        left-text 2.1

        \lipsum[1-3]

        left-text 2.2

        \vfill
    }
    \ParallelRText{ %
        right-text 2.1

        \lipsum[1-3]

        right-text 2.2

        \vfill
    }
    \ParallelPar

\end{Parallel}

After

Text between.

\lipsum[1-6]

Text between.

\begin{Parallel}[p]{}{} %{\linewidth}{\linewidth}
    \ParallelLText{ %
        left-text 3.1

        \lipsum[1-5]

        left-text 3.2

        \vfill

    }
    \ParallelRText{ %
        right-text 3.1

        \lipsum[1-5]

        right-text 3.2

        \vfill
    }
    \ParallelPar
    \ParallelLText{left-text 4}
    \ParallelRText{right-text 4}
    \ParallelPar

    \renewcommand{\ParallelAtEnd}{text at end}
\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

Comment: After compiling it's a bit hard to follow, whether or not parallel works as you need. So I suggest replacing \lipsum with \blindtext (https://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext), which supports at least (n)german, english, american, latin, french, catalan, to make things even more evident. // The author offers to add more languages. See the manual for his requirements.